# What are the definitions of Weather and Memory in xmobar repo?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, existential-type, xmobar

Playing around with xmobar, when I saw [this](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/etc/xmobar.hs)

```hs
  , commands = [ Run $ Weather "EGPH" ["-t","<station>: <tempC>C",
                                        "-L","18","-H","25",
                                        "--normal","green",
                                        "--high","red",
                                        "--low","lightblue"] 36000
               , Run $ Network "eth0" ["-L","0","-H","32",
                                        "--normal","green","--high","red"] 10
               , Run $ Network "eth1" ["-L","0","-H","32",
                                        "--normal","green","--high","red"] 10
               , Run $ Cpu ["-L","3","-H","50",
                             "--normal","green","--high","red"] 10
               , Run $ Memory ["-t","Mem: <usedratio>%"] 10
               , Run $ Swap [] 10
               , Run $ Com "uname" ["-s","-r"] "" 36000
               , Run $ Date "%a %b %_d %Y %H:%M:%S" "date" 10
              , Run HelloWorld
              ]
```

I without thinking too much I said *"oh, I can pull that `Run` out"* and wrote

```hs
  , commands = Run <$> [Weather {- ... -}
               , Network {- ... -}
               , Network {- ... -}
               , Cpu {- ... -}
               , Memory {- ... -}
               , Swap {- ... -}
               , Com {- ... -}
               , Date  {- ... -}
               , HelloWorld
               ]
```

but this obviously doesn't work, because for instance `Data`, `HelloWorld` and `Weather` are different types.

But some *can* go together within a list, e.g. this type checks

```hs
foo = [ Weather undefined undefined undefined
      , Cpu undefined undefined
      , DiskU undefined undefined undefined
      , Memory undefined undefined ]
```

but this doesn't

```hs
foo = [ Weather undefined undefined undefined
      , Cpu undefined undefined
      , DiskU undefined undefined undefined
      , Date undefined undefined undefined -- because of this
      , Memory undefined undefined ]
```

Now I see that [`Date` is an actual `data` type](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/commit/3386a05f22ec14ad6383228771966b2f82ae6a58/src/Xmobar/Plugins/Date.hs#L31), but what are the others?

If I open [`Weather`](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/src/Xmobar/Plugins/Monitors/Weather.hs) I don't even see the single word `Weather` other than in [a comment](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/commit/3386a05f22ec14ad6383228771966b2f82ae6a58/src/Xmobar/Plugins/Monitors/Weather.hs#L4) and in [the name of the `module`](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/src/Xmobar/Plugins/Monitors/Weather.hs#L16).

So what is `Weather`? And *where* do I see its definition?

The fact that `Weather` and, say, `Memory` can go in the same list makes me think of [existential types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type) of which I have little experience. However, from that wiki page, I see that this

```hs
data Worker x y = forall b. Buffer b => Worker {buffer :: b, input :: x, output :: y}
```

is the way of defining a `Worker` that can hold a `buffer` of whatever type, as long as that type implements `Buffer`.

Now, given that the type of the first `foo` above has type `[Monitors]`, I guess that `Monitors` is playing the role of `Worker`, the existential type, and `Weather`, `Memory` and others are value constructors of types that implement whatever interface (corresponding to `Buffer`) is constraining the the type that the existential type `Monitors` can wrap. But `Date` doesn't implement that interface, so it can't go with the others.

Is it like this?

But if that's the case... then where are `Weather`'s, `Memory`'s and others' definitions, togheter with their implementation of the interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of searching in just the Weather.hs file, search in the whole repository. You will find `Monitors.hs` features [a definition of `Weather`](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/commit/3386a05f22ec14ad6383228771966b2f82ae6a58/src/Xmobar/Plugins/Monitors.hs#L62):

```
data Monitors = Network      Interface   Args Rate
              -- ...
              | DiskU        DiskSpec    Args Rate
              -- ...
              | Memory       Args        Rate
              | Swap         Args        Rate
              | Cpu          Args        Rate
              -- ...
#ifdef WEATHER
              | Weather      Station     Args Rate
              | WeatherX     Station SkyConditions Args Rate
#endif
              -- ...
```

It is not an existential type, just an ordinary Haskell algebraic data type, so there is no "interface" to support. They can go in a list together because they are all of the same type (`Monitors`).

You could also find this out by reading the [Haddock documentation for xmobar](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmobar-0.29/docs/doc-index-W.html) instead of poring through the source. It's nicely indexed and cross-linked so you can find the definitions you're looking for, and links to the source if you want to see more details.

There is a closely related existential type `Runnable`, [defined in `Runnable.hs`](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/commit/3386a05f22ec14ad6383228771966b2f82ae6a58/src/Xmobar/Run/Runnable.hs#L29), as

```
data Runnable = forall r . (Exec r, Read r, Show r) => Run r
```

This is the existential type that allows `Run $ Date ...` to be in the same list as the other monitors like `Run $ Memory ...`, even though the `Date` type and `Monitors` type are not directly related. They each satisfy the `Runnable` constraints, and the `Runnable` wrapper hides all their other details so they can be treated uniformly.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was convinced `Weather` was a type because HLS, if I hover on the word `Weather` in `Run $ Weather ...`, shows only `Weather`, so I thought it was the type (not the value ctor), whereas if I define, say, `data Foo = Bar | Baz` and `foos = [Bar, Baz]`, then hovering on `Bar` in the `foos` HLS shows `Bar :: Foo`, which clearly shows me the value construtor _and_ the type :/

Comment: It can't really be a type, because it's occurring in value position. You couldn't write `succ Int`, because `Int` is a type, and `succ` is a function on values. It's the same thing for `Run $ Weather ...`: the result of `Run` is going into a list value, so it must work with values, not types. I can't help you re: HLS, but I would guess it doesn't know the definition of `Weather`, so it just displays what little it knows: its name.

Comment: Yeah, regarding the type. I'm definitely a bit rusty.